# Nginx 301 redirect not redirecting

Tags: url, redirect, nginx, centos

I'm currently trying to redirect by non-www hostname into a www. one. The server is CentOS 6 with NGINX.

I've tried both return and rewrite commands to no avail. These being as follows:

```
server {
listen       80;
server_name  rholloway.co.uk;
return       301 http://www.rholloway.co.uk$request_uri;
}
```

and

```
rewrite ^ http://www.rholloway.co.uk$request_uri? permanent;
```

Both versions then have a following www. server block. What happens once I reload Nginx is that the non-www address breaks, and can no longer access the page (though can strangely access the pages under said name, without any redirecting).

If anyone can help me to get this working, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The configuration looks fine. You can test the `nginx` configuration using `nginx -T`. Look at the access and error logs to find out what is happening. Do you have DNS for both domains pointing to this server?

Comment: Yes, they both point to the server. When I'm not trying to redirect both connect perfectly fine. The logs seem to be saying that when I'm attempting to redirect the directory index for the non-www becomes forbidden. Not totally clear why.

Comment: The cause is unclear. You should consider editing your question and adding the other server block, the relevant contents of access and error logs, and the results of a curl request together with the expected result.